# Programming a "Lean left and Lean right" - Gesture in Kinect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, gestures

I'm programming an game in unity 3d, where I am mapping the kinect skeleton on a 3d model.

Now I have to check, if the player is leaning left or right... and here is my problem.

I've followed this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/08/08/writing-a-gesture-service-with-the-kinect-for-windows-sdk.aspx

And now, I'm looking for a correct implementation of the lean-geasture.

Does anyone of you have an idea, how I can solve this problem? I have to make this gesture in some parts, so i can recognize a leaning. I've tried something like: `if left shoulder.x < hips_left.x or left.shoulder.x > hips_left.x` but that doesn't work so good...

I really need your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use someting like that perhaps combined with your idea

```
if(left.shoulder.y == right.shoulder.y){
    //No Direction
}else if(left.shoulder.y < right.shoulder.y){
    //leaning left
}else{
    //leaning right
}
```

Maybe you can use the head.x pos too

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this works perfect but in my tests it does work

```
if((left.shoulder.y + tollerance) >= right.shoulder.y && (left.shoulder.y - tollerance) <= right.shoulder.y){
    //No Direction
}else if(left.shoulder.y < right.shoulder.y){
    //leaning left
}else{
    //leaning right
}
```

Comment: Hey, well i think this can work with my idea! i'll give it a try. thanks!

Comment: To reduce the false positives, you should also use a threshold. A condition could look like this, then: left.shoulder.y < right.shoulder.y + yourThresholdValue. The higher yourThresholdValue, the more a user has to lean to the respective direction to cause the desired action.

Comment: I would add the thresholdValue at the beginning that you have the threshold in both directions